# Fix MKPointAnnotation to centre of MapKit even while scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, mapkitannotation

i want to make MKPointAnnotation fixed to centre of the map even while scrolling, i try to make it but MKPointAnnotation is not move while scrolling
here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myMap: MKMapView!
private var locationManager = CLLocationManager();
private var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?;
//    private var riderLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
initializeLocationManager()}

// find location on the map
private func initializeLocationManager(){
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

// if we hade the coordinate from the manager
if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
// the place the map will show (ZOOM LVL ON MAP)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation!, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

//To Remove annotation = Point on map befor add new one
myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)

//Show My Point At Map
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation();
annotation.coordinate = myMap.centerCoordinate
myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
// Show My Point At Map
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = myMap.region.center // instead of myMap.centerCoordinate
myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

**EDIT:**

You need to call `stopUpdatingLocation()` in  `didUpdateLocations` method.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    // if we hade the coordinate from the manager
    if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
        // the place the map will show (ZOOM LVL ON MAP)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation!, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() // <- Stop updating
    }
}
```

And you should use `regionDidChangeAnimated` method to make MKPointAnnotation fixed to centre of the map even while scrolling,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    // To Remove annotation = Point on map befor add new one
    myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation();
    annotation.coordinate = myMap.region.center
    myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works, but when i try to scroll on map it move for less than 1sec and come back to the same region i start do you know how to solve that and thanks again for your help